I can't use the "cat" command
When I run the "cat file.txt" command, I get the response:
cat file.txt
zsh: command not found: bat

This is on Kali Linux 2024.1 that I just installed on VMware Player, updated, and installed Kitty.

If you type the command alias and press Return, does one of the lines in the output read as cat=bat ?

Yes, and bat is installed on the system.

Type: unalias cat

for even more fun sudo apt install lolcat and then alias cat=lolcat.

Seems like you have "cat" aliased to "bat" (see sharkdp/bat). You could install it (sudo apt install -y bat) if you want to actually use bat, or use cat itself by surrounding its name in quotes ("cat" file.txt) or using its path (/usr/bin/cat file.txt).
You can remove the alias using unalias cat in zsh, but the alias might be set somewhere like .zshrc, so if you want to use cat instead of bat, it's worth finding out if/where the alias is set up.
Edit: The command for bat may have been changed to batcat per a recent-ish update. If you think bat should be working, try using the batcat command instead.

another way to temporary unalias is the use of \ e.g. \cat

Excellent, I changed the alias to batcat and everything worked correctly. Thanks.
